# RabbitMQ and EventMachine::defer

Tags: ruby, rabbitmq, eventmachine

I am trying to get my head round RabbitMQ. I want one queue to listen, and when it receives a message I want it to reply to an anonymous queue that is specified via the `reply_to` header with multiple messages.

So far I have the following task that is both the consumer and the subscriber for the `reply_to` message:

```
desc "start_consumer", "start the test consumer"
def start_consumer
  puts "Running #{AMQP::VERSION} version of the gem"

      AMQP.start(:host => "localhost", :user => "guest", :password => "guest", :vhost => "/", 
                        :logging => true, :port => 5672) do |connection|

        channel = AMQP::Channel.new(connection)

        requests_queue = channel.queue("one", :exclusive => true, :auto_delete => true)

        Signal.trap("INT") do
          connection.close do
            EM.stop{exit}
          end
        end

        channel.prefetch(1)

        requests_queue.subscribe(:ack => true) do |header, body|
          puts "received in server #{body.inspect}"

          (0..5).each do |n|
            header.ack

            reply = {:reply => "Respone #{n}", :is_last => (n == 5)}

            AMQP::Exchange.default.publish(
                                            MultiJson.encode(reply), 
                                            :routing_key => header.reply_to,
                                            :correlation_id => header.correlation_id
                                          )


            sleep(2)
          end
        end

        puts " [x] Awaiting RPC requests"
      end          
    end
```

My calling code is:

```
  def publish(urlSearch, routing_key)
    EM.run do

      corr_id = rand(10_000_000).to_s

      requests ||= Hash.new

      connection = AMQP.connect(:host => "localhost")

      callback_queue = AMQP::Channel.new(connection).queue("", :exclusive => true)             

      callback_queue.subscribe do |header, body|

        reply = MultiJson.decode(body)               

        if reply[:is_last.to_s]  
          connection.close do
            EM.stop{exit}
          end
        end
      end                          

      callback_queue.append_callback(:declare) do
        AMQP::Exchange.default.publish(MultiJson.encode(urlSearch), :routing_key => routing_key, :reply_to => callback_queue.name, :correlation_id => corr_id)
      end

    end
```

The problem is that messages are not sent until the all the messages in the iteration have been published.

That is after the iteration in the `(0..5)` loop has finished then all the messages are published.

Someone told me that using `EventMachine::defer` might be an option but I am not sure how to apply this to the loop.

Can anyone suggest a pointer of how to solve this problem? Is `EventMachine::defer` a good option and, if so, how do I do this when using `AMQP.start`?

Answer (score 0):

The thing to remember when working with EM is that the reactor itself is single threaded. So, the reason it waits until the loop is finished before anything sends is because the loop is taking up that single thread. (You really, really, really don't want to use sleep in an EM application. You're blocking the entire reactor and nothing will happen.)

If you want the messages to publish, or other really any other EM action to happen (timers fired, other data received, etc) you have to let the reactor loop.

You could use something like the EM::Iterator to schedule the work for you, something like:

```
EM::Iterator.new(0..5).each do |n, iter|
  reply = {:reply => "Response #{n}", :is_last => (n == 5)}
  AMQP::Exchange.default.publish(MultiJson.encode(reply), 
                                 :routing_key => header.reply_to,
                                 :correlation_id => header.correlation_id)
  iter.next
end
header.ack
```

Comment: I ended up using EM.defer https://gist.github.com/1480745.  I am using JRuby, maybe I should think about using Java threads.